# Understanding notation regarding particles states and wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, notation

In the development in my notes of second quantisation I have a problem in understanding notation.

We start by considering a basis $\psi_i(\mathbf{r})$ for the Hilbert space of single particle wavefunctions and then build it to a basis of the Hilbert space of two particles (bosons or fermions). We then generalise this to the case of $N$ particles.

> For $N$-particle systems the wavefunction can be written as $\psi_{i_1,\dots,i_N}(\mathbf{r}_1,\dots,\mathbf{r}_N)$. We want to build a basis similar to the case of two particles $\dots$ Let $\psi_{i_1,\dots,i_N}(\mathbf{r}_1,\dots,\mathbf{r}_N)$ be the many particle state in which the single particle states $i_1,\dots,i_N$ are occupied (for bosons some or all of the states may coincide). One might at first consider the product state $\psi_{i_1}(\mathbf{r}_1)\dots \psi_{i_N}(\mathbf{r}_N)$ $\dots$

I cannot understand what this means physically. If we know there is a particle(s) in state $i_1$ why do we need $\mathbf{r}_1$? Does the state $i_1$ not specify position? Also what exactly does this mean by *state*, I thought that the wavefunction was the state? Furthemore how does this relate to a *site*?

Comment: Could you please add some more context? What was this in relation to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we know there is a particle(s) in state $i_1$ why do we need
>   $r_1$? Does the state $i_1$ not specify position?

The fact that the particle is in a state $|\psi\rangle$ does not specify the particle's position - it specifies the wave-function
$$
\langle x | \psi \rangle = \psi(x)
$$
from which one can find
$$|\psi(x)|^2$$ 
This is the probability density for observing the particle $\psi$ at position $x$ -  a distribution over $x$. It does not specify that the particle $\psi$ is at the position $x$.

> what exactly does this mean by state, I thought that the wavefunction
>   was the state?

The wave-function $\psi(x)$ is one representation of the state - a particular choice of (position) basis states, in this case
$$|\psi\rangle  = \int dx \psi(x) |x\rangle$$
This is similar to representing a wavefunction as vector $\psi_i$ in some basis states $|i\rangle$, e.g.
$$|\psi\rangle  = \sum \psi_i |i\rangle$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1 \rangle} \newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle #1 \rvert}$The [*states*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Conceptual_description) of a quantum system are nothing else than the *abstract* vectors in the Hilbert space of states $\mathcal{H}$. For one particle, given a basis of position eigenkets $\ket{x}$ with $\hat{x}\ket{x_0} = x_0\ket{x_0}$ and a state $\ket{i}\in\mathcal{H}$, the wavefunction is
$$ \psi_{\ket{i}}(x) := \langle x \vert i \rangle $$
and since the map $\mathcal{H} \to L^2(x), \ket{i} \mapsto \psi_{\ket{i}}$ is an isomorphism of the abstract space of states to the space of wavefunctions, the wavefunction contains all information the abstract state contains. Thus, you may also say that the wavefunction *is* the state.

If we have more than one particle, the space of states of the total system is the $N$-fold tensor product of the single particle states, and the wavefunction is then
$$ \psi_{\ket{i}}(x_1,\dots,x_N) := (\bra{x_1}\otimes \dots \otimes \bra{x_N})\ket{i}$$
where $\ket{i}$ is an $N$-particle state that *may* consist of single-particle states $\ket{i_1},\dots,\ket{i_N}$ as $\ket{i} = \ket{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes\ket{i_N}$, but could also be an entangled state for which such a decomposition is impossible.